# How to organize ASP.NET request locking or row locking in DB

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, locking, blocking

I've asp.net page/handler to access images.
When performed fist request to the image I resize image to standard size(save on disk) and return it.
So I need lock all request to the image except one. This one will resize image.
Image identified by ID in URL, so I guess one lock object required per one image(ID in URL).
My question is How can I organize this lock model?

My idea add lock object in Application (Application is synchronized)
like this Application.Add(Request[Id], new object());
and use it to locking competitive threads.

This task like row locking of DB or locking element in collection.

Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is locking image file with.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("image.file", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{

resize image here 

}
```

When second(third etc) thread try to create file the Exception "The process cannot access the file ..." will throw. And I process this exception in code.